# Issue in regex pattern matching using gawk, grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, gawk

I have a file "Input_file" with content like this

```
%name=ABC
%value=123
sample text in file
sample text in file
%name=XYZ
%value=789
sample text in file
```

I need to extract the lines of this file matching this pattern.

```
str="%name=*\n%value=*"
```

I was working this way

```
gawk -v st=$str '/"$st"/ {print}' $Input_file
```

I'm getting the error

```
gawk:              ^ backslash not last character on line
```

Even with grep as in

```
grep -e "$str" $Input_file
```

it says there is no such matching pattern. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Firstly -- `grep` is line-oriented, so a multiline pattern will never match. Secondly -- `gawk` is line-oriented by default, so if you want a multiline pattern to match, you need to set [the record separator `RS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records) to something appropriate. Thirdly -- for debugging purposes, I think you're better off writing your `gawk` command directly (e.g. `gawk '/%name=*\n%value=*/ {print}'`, rather than using Bash variables and so on, since in the latter case it can be hard to tell whether the problem is on the AWK end or on the Bash end.

Comment: Fourthly -- `=*` means "zero or more equals signs". For "an equals sign, plus zero or more characters", write `=.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -A1 "^%name=" $Input_file | grep -B1 "^%value=" | grep -v "^--"
```

Comment: And just in case `%name=` and `%value=` shows up in the sample text, you might what to be a little safer with `grep -A1 "^%name=" $Input_file | grep -B1 "^%value=" | grep -v "^--"`. It might be overkill...

Comment: @ToddR Indeed. I actually meant to anchor the first two patterns as well, but then forgot.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot directly use your "pattern (str)"  in awk. because awk default doesn't work in multi-line mode. However you could do this with awk:

```
 awk '/^%name=/{n=$0;next}/^%value=/&&n{print n"\n"$0}{n=""}' file
```

with your example, the above one-liner outputs:

```
%name=ABC
%value=123
%name=XYZ
%value=789
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different syntax in your $str variable, the '*' is useless in because you are searching a pattern not a literal value, for gawk I can't help sorry

try this:

```
str="\%name=|\%value="
egrep $str $input_file
```

So you can match the two criteria of you search

Comment: this will do something different. it will find all "name=" and "value=" even if they are **NOT** adjacent lines

Comment: I know but in his example of the data he need to parse are always paired, maybe my approach was too simplistic